# Split json file into multiple flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a json file such as below, i need to split this flowfile into numbers of flowfile as per each line

Input flowfile:

{a:122, b: 12, c: dev}

{b: 19, c: dev}

{a:111, b: 12, c: roman,d: 2.3}

Output Flowfile will have 3 files with each row.

Splitjson is just just spliting the first line, please suggest

Comment: Not sure why this question was put on hold, It is clear what this question is asking, and both answers below are correct as alternative solutions

Comment: I agree, what's unclear?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have downstream processors that expect one JSON per flow file? Otherwise you may be able to skip the Split entirely and just use the Record processors (ConvertRecord, PutDatabaseRecord, e.g.). The JsonTreeReader (in later versions of NiFi) accept the one-JSON-per-line format (even though that's not valid JSON per se). If you do need one JSON object per flowfile, Bryan's suggestion of SplitText with a Line Count of 1 is spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

SplitText with line count of 1

Comment: @devD I apologize for the short reply, but I assumed since you had tried SplitJson already that my answer would make sense, hopefully it did solve your problem